# How can I open .cpr (Cubase) files?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

I have a bunch of old `.cpr`. Those are project files created with Cubase. In my case they do not contain audio, just midi.

I would like to open them. How can I do that?

PS: The files were made with an LE version of Cubase which I fear I cannot install with wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPR file is a Cubase Project file which belongs to the Steinberg Cubase music composition software.  Unfortunately you can only open them natively in Windows and MAC OS.  So to be able to open them under Ubuntu, you may look into using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Or you could try using the Cubase Elements to open your .cpr files and save as Standard MIDI Files .mid, which virtually anything can open.